# Unable to create an object of type 'RepositoryContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> Unable to create an object of type 'RepositoryContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

```csharp
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace StoreApp.Models
{
  public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
  
    public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> Options) : base(Options)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Javascript. Please tag your questions appropriately

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the link? Everything is described there.

Comment: Have you configured your database e.g `AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>`

Comment: i'm doing it together with a course video and I did exactly the same as what was done there, but it gave an error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try configure connectionstring directly.

```
    public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            //Setup connectionstring directly
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog = AhanoDB; Integrated Security = true"); 
        }
    }
```

And you still need

```
Services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>();
```